# Firefox Focus crashes after uninstalling Google WebView

Tags: webview

I uninstall **Android System WebView** with `adb shell` using the following commands.

```
pm uninstall com.google.android.webview
pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.webview
```

Now, when I launch Firefox Focus and type any website to visit, it crashes and shows the warning, but the normal Firefox Browser works without any issue.

[image: Screenshot_Firefox_Focus]

**Question:** Though Play Store shows "Android WebView is a system component powered by Chrome", does Firefox Focus (FF) depend on that Android WebView? Can FF be run without WebView as normal Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** As of Oct 2018, [FireFox Focus now uses the GeckoView engine for rendering](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2018/10/02/new-firefox-focus-comes-with-search-suggestions-revamped-visual-design-and-an-under-the-hood-surprise-for-android-users/)

<s>**TL;DR:** Yes FireFox Focus depends on the Android System WebView with plans to switch to GeckoView when its ready. So **NO** you can't remove the Android System WebView and expect the app to work (as of Jan 2018).</s>

So Firefox Focus is an open source project:

https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android

Looking at the project, there isn't much code there but does pull a library called:

`geckoview-latest.arr`

From what I can tell from this mailing list post (after following a few links from the main page README):

https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/firefox-focus-public/2017-October/000018.html

and this issue:

https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/issues/13

states that the team started the Firefox Focus project using Android's WebView while waiting for GeckoView to reach Minimum Viable Product (MVP).

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1322573

The fact that not everything in the *Depends On* list is crossed off means that GeckoView is a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub link. I find the dependency in [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml). Can I remove the dependency from APK file of FF?

Comment: The last line in the AndroidManifest.xml is only for opt-out yes/no for sending metrics back to Google. The app will *NOT* work without Android System WebView. You may want to read through the links I provided to get context.